# Can we somehow compute $(z^2 - 1)(z^2 - 4)(z^2 - 9)(z^2 - 16) \cdots (z^2 - k^2)$ in half the number of operations?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, factorial, computational-complexity, products

Let $f(z, k) = (z^2 - 1)(z^2 - 2^2)(z^2 - 3^2)(z^2 - 4^2) \cdots (z^2 - k^2)$ in less than $1 + k + k + k + (k-1) = 4k$ arithmetic operations, specifically I need it to be roughly $2k$ operations or less.

In the cost formula, the first $1$ comes from needing to square $z$, the first $k$ from incrementing a counter $k$ times to make up $1, 2, 3, \dots k$, i.e. you don't get to have arbitrary constants or tables of constants which really wouldn't add much efficiency anyway.  The second $k$ comes from squaring each $k$, the third $k$ comes from the subtraction in each parenthesis.  The $(k-1)$ comes from the $(k-1)$ multiplications.  So that the totals is $4k$ arithmetic operations if computed directly using the given formula for $f$.

Where does this come from?  These are the factors (combined) in $\dfrac{x!}{(x - 2k - 1)!}$ where $z$ is taken to the median factor in the sequence $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (z+1)z(z-1) \cdots (z-k)$.  I don't know if that is 100% accurate, but that part doesn't matter.  Just to tell you where it comes from.  Computing *this* directly requires twice as many operations as $f(z,k)$.  So already in computing a factorial I've reduced the operations by half.  So I'm just wondering if we can or can't find a way of reducing it by another half.

> **Question.** How can we compute $f(z,k)$ in $2k$ arithmetic operations or less (roughly)?

If you can do it with $\dfrac{8k}{5}$ operations or something that would also be interesting if you get my drift.

---

This might help because of group theory: All the arithmetic is done modulo some $n\in \Bbb{N}\setminus 1$ and $\sqrt{n} \geq z,k$.  But note $n$ will be huge or 1000's of digits (think RSA numbers that are hard to factor).  But also note that we can take each $1,2,3,\dots, k$ as well as $z$ to be coprime to $n$ because in any factorization algorithm you can check the result of every arithmetic operation and only add a polynomial factor slow-down (the cost of computing $\gcd(x\pmod n, n)$).  Thus on the right we have that the results of all arithmetic operations are units in $\Bbb{Z}/n$.  If it turns out that they're not, then we can halt the algorithm because a factor has been found or $\gcd(x\pmod n, n) = n$ in which case we can stop computing the long factorial and change the binary search parameters to another range $[y,x]$ because a $\gcd$ result of $n$ would indicate "you've gone too far" and included all factors of $n$, so back up and try again.

Because of coprimality, the set $\{ y^2 \pmod n\} \leqslant (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ forms a subgroup of the units.  We're also able to "pretend that we're working in a field" because of this, that is until a factor is found.  I know that other integer factorization algorithms do just that.

Comment: The title... the third term should be $z^2-9$.

Comment: I fixed the title. (But I don't know an answer, sorry.)

Comment: Maybe grouping symmetric pairs: $(z^2-j^2)(z^2-(k-j+1)^2) = (z^2+j(k-j+1))^2 - (k+1)^2z^2$

Comment: @dxiv that is interesting, care to make an answer? :)  How did you derive that so quickly and symmetric about what factor?

Comment: Have you considered the $\Gamma$ function? You could rewrite what you want to solve as $$\dfrac{\Gamma(z+k+1)}{z\Gamma(z-k)}$$ and I'm pretty sure the Gamma function converges pretty quickly, so it should be pretty easy to compute. For large $k$ it is probably a faster approach than factorial. You may only need to compute a few terms of the series for the numerator and denominator to get a very close approximation.

Comment: @SlipEternal unfortunately I need an exact formula for taking modulo $n$ or a large integer to factor.  Having to linearly search around the gamma result would not make things more efficient from my experience coding stuff.

Comment: @dxiv how many operations total does that method give?

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics Haven't counted, think it comes out cheaper than the direct product, though maybe not by half. The idea is to factor each difference of squares then recombine into a different difference of squares. When there is such central symmetry, it is worth trying to exploit it.

Comment: @dxiv please teach me your methods in an answer :)

Comment: Can anyone prove that no such algorithm exists? LOL!

Comment: Everything is done modulo $n\in \Bbb{N}$ a value independent of $z, k$ but $z, k \lt n$.  I don't think that would help though, but does it?  Also we can assume that all $1, 2, \dots, k$ are coprime to $n$.  That might help as then you'd have a subgroup of squares of the group of units modulo $n$.  Groups, symmetry, etc.

Comment: @dxiv the expression on the left takes $7$ ops and the one on the right takes $6$ ops, where is the optimization ? :)  I need it to be roughly $4$ ops!

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics I said it's worth trying, not that it guarantees half the ops ;-)

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics Are you sure that you focus to the appropriate numbers? You do not distinguish between multiplication and addition. But multiplication usually is much more expensive than addition.  So often a lot of additions is faster than a multiplication. An example: calculting $k^2$ directly  is usually much more expensive than calculating $k^2$ recursively by $k^2=(k-1)^2+2k+1$.

Comment: @miracle173 yes I'm sure.  I'm just roughly measuring.  In my measurement, if I come up with a polynomial-time algorithm that implies a polynomial-time algorithm in the optimized mult. system and vise versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, the central symmetry of the product suggests looking at symmetric pairs:

$$
\begin{align}
(z^2-j^2)(z^2-(k-j+1)^2) &=\color{red}{(z-j)}\color{blue}{(z+j)}\color{red}{\big(z-(k+1-j)\big)}\color{blue}{\big(z+(k+1-j)\big)}
\\ &= \color{red}{\big(z^2 - (k+1)z +j(k+1-j)\big)}\color{blue}{\big(z^2 + (k+1)z +j(k+1-j)\big)}
\\ &= \big(z^2+j(k+1-j)\big)^2 - (k+1)^2z^2
\\ &= \big(z^2+n_j\big)^2 - (k+1)^2z^2
\end{align}
$$

Here $\,n_j=j(k+1-j)\,$, which can be calculated recursively with $\,n_1=k\,$ and $\,n_{j+1}=n_{j}+k-2j\,$.

For $\,j=1\,$ to $\,k/2\,$, an approximate count ignoring some half $\,1/2\,$ ops:

- the sequence $\,k-2j\,$ can be calculated iteratively by subtracting $\,2\,$ at each step, total $\,k/2\,$ ops;
- the sequence $\,n_{j+1}=n_j+(k-2j)\,$ then takes one addition at each step, total $\,k/2\,$ ops;
- the term $\,\big(z^2+n_j\big)^2\,$ takes $\, 2 \cdot k/2 = k\,$ ops;
- the difference of terms takes $\,k/2\,$ op.
- the multiplication of pairs take $\,k/2\,$ ops.

In the end, it adds up to about $\,3k\,$ ops, which is slightly better than the baseline, but still short of the target $\,2k\,$.

Comment: Okay so it takes $\dfrac{3}{4}$ the time.   Perhaps applying it  again and again since what you've done is brilliant - converted it into another problem of the same form - a product of diffs of squares.  However, it might get harder to see the symmetries perhaps?

Comment: I'm currently looking into how the $k$'s are $1, 2, 4, 6, 8, \dots$ unioned with $1,3,6,9,12, \dots$ unioned with $1,5,10,15, \dots$ etc.

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics That's a tempting thought, though I don't know how well it can work out, since there comes a point of diminishing returns with such manipulations. Without having much context, one thing that looks a bit odd is that you count all arithmetic operations equally. Maybe there are hidden $\,\bmod\,$ along the way involving divisions that trump the rest, but otherwise addition is generally cheaper than multiplication. FWIW the calculation above has about half the multiplications of the direct method.

Comment: I'm thinking more in terms of provable asymptotic algorithm complexity.  Counting the arithmetic ops I thought was as good enough measure for starting out.

Answer (score 3):

Using $(n+1)^2=n^2+(2n+1)$,
set $m=1, j=3, y=z^2-1, p=y$.

Then
$m=m+j, j=j+2, y=y-m, p=p*y$
until $j=(k+1)^2$.

So $j=3, 5, 7, ...,
m=1, 4, 9, ...,
y=z^2-1, z^2-4, ...
$.

Each step takes 2 adds, 1 subtract,
and 1 multiply.

Don't immediately how to do it faster.

Comment: How many ops is that?

Comment: It's about the same but simpler. A multiply has been replaced by an add. If k is fixed, you can get the explicit polynomial and then use Horner's rule.

Comment: The same as $4k$ or $2k$?

Comment: $k$ will change all around in the larger algorithm I want to code.

Comment: I think that should be $y=y-j$, and you don't need $m$

Answer (score 2):

This method is similar to marty cohen's.  It uses recursive addition to evaluate polynomials.
It takes $2$ adds and $1/2$ a multiply for each of your quadratic factors $(z^2-i^2)$.
I don't know if your language requires an extra step for a counter that you don't use, but that would be an extra half an add.
Take the $(z^2-i^2)$ in pairs.
$$G(z,m)=(z^2-(2m-1)^2)(z^2-(2m)^2)$$
$G(z,m)$ is a degree-4 polynomial in $m$.  Define
$$H(z,m)=G(z,m+1)-G(z,m)\\
I(z,m)=H(z,m+1)-H(z,m)\\
J(z,m)=I(z,m+1)-I(z,m)\\
K(z)=J(z,m+1)-J(z,m)$$
$H(z,m)$ is cubic in $m$, $I(z,m)$ is quadratic in $m$, $J(z,m)$ is linear in $m$ and $K(z)$ is independent of $m$.
Each of $J,I,H,G$ can be calculated with one addition.
$$J(z,m+1)=J(z,m)+K(z)\\
I(z,m+1)=I(z,m)+J(z,m)\\
H(z,m+1)=H(z,m)+I(z,m)\\
G(z,m+1)=G(z,m)+H(z,m)$$
So each $G(z,m)$ can be calculated in a total of four additions.
Multiply them all together as you go along, with one multiply per pair.
You don't need subscripts as you overwrite $G,H,I,J$ as you go.
A similar trick, with $7k/3$ or $8k/3$ steps per $(z^2-i^2)$, works if you group the $(z^2-i^2)$ in threes, and so on.

Comment: How many ops total does it take in $k$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure $5/2$ or $3$, depending on whether you need a step to update $m$